# How to center element verically and horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to centre object in the middle of screen. I have used margin: 0 auto. I have no idea for centring vertically! Also How can I make border in h2 to surround only the text not the whole width
?

html

```css
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #section1 {
      background: #FEC56B;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    #section2 {
      background: #51C5D4;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    #section3 {
      background: #80D4DF;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    #section1 h2 {
      margin-top: 0px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      font-size: 60px;
      color: white;
      padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="section1">
  <h2>Be awesome!</h2>
</div>

<div id="section2">
</div>

<div id="section3">
</div>
```

Comment: which you want to center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#section1 h2{

  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;left:0;height:60px;width:350px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! Can you explain your code a little please? I am a beginner!

Comment: Can you explain how you calculated 60px and 350px?

Comment: In default, h2 tag takes width and height from parent. so please u set height and width for h2 tag.So it surronds only the text. And U set position absolute for this element and easily u can align the element center of the screen now.

Comment: Based on the font size U can set the height and width of the element.

Comment: this is **not** a good solution. It works here, but what happens when you want to change the content?

Answer (score 0):

### try this this what you want

simple add this `text-align: center;` to  `#section1 h2{` **bellow is snippet run bellow snippet**

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#section1{
  background: #FEC56B;
  height: 100vh;
}

#section2{
  
  background: #51C5D4;
  height:100vh;
}

#section3{
  background: #80D4DF; 
  height:100vh;
}

#section1 h2{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id ="section1">
    <h2>Be awesome!</h2>
</div>

<div id ="section2">
</div>

<div id ="section3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#section1{
  background: #FEC56B;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align:center;
}

#section2{
  background: #51C5D4;
  height:100vh;
}

#section3{
  background: #80D4DF; 
  height:100vh;
}

#section1 h2{
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id ="section1">
    <h2>Be awesome!</h2>
</div>

<div id ="section2">
</div>

<div id ="section3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}

#section1{
  background: #FEC56B;
  height: 100vh;
}

#section2{
  
  background: #51C5D4;
  height:100vh;
}

#section3{
  background: #80D4DF; 
  height:100vh;
}

#section1 h2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
    <div id ="section1">
        <h2>Be awesome!</h2>
    </div>

<div id ="section2">
</div>

<div id ="section3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}

#section1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fec56b;
    float: left;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#section2{
  
  background: #51C5D4;
  height:100vh;
}

#section3{
  background: #80D4DF; 
  height:100vh;
}


#section1 h2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 100vh;
    margin: -394px 0 0 -157px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
    <div id ="section1">
        <h2>Be awesome!</h2>
    </div>

    <div id ="section2">
    </div>

    <div id ="section3">
    </div>
```